# playwright-python parallelize scraping of list of urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, parallel-processing, playwright, playwright-python

I have a list of URLs. While iterating over the list, each URL is opened by a new page using `context.new_page().goto(URL)`. I want to open multiple pages and scrape in parallel.
note: each new page opens up a new tab with the URL specified

I tried the following code snippet using joblib.

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def fetch_info(profile, _page):
        name_path = "body > div.profile.sm-col-10.lg-col-9.mt1.content-max-width.mx-auto.clearfix > div.flex.flex-wrap.relative.mb2 > div.profile-text.ps1 > div.flex.items-center.mt2 > h2"
        gender_path = "body > div.profile.sm-col-10.lg-col-9.mt1.content-max-width.mx-auto.clearfix > div.flex.flex-wrap.relative.mb2 > div.profile-text.ps1 > p.mt1.mb0.line-height-4"
        age_path = "body > div.profile.sm-col-10.lg-col-9.mt1.content-max-width.mx-auto.clearfix > div.flex.flex-wrap.relative.mb2 > div.profile-text.ps1 > p:nth-child(3)"
        image_path = "#big-photo > img"

        name = _page.locator(name_path).inner_html()
        gender = _page.locator(gender_path).inner_html()
        age = _page.locator(age_path).inner_html()
        image = _page.locator(image_path).get_attribute("src")
        
        def clean_data(text):
            return text.strip().replace("\n","")

        name, gender, age, image = clean_data(name), clean_data(gender), clean_data(age),clean_data(image)
        gender = gender.split("/")[0].strip()
        age = age.split('•')[0].strip()
        user = {
            "name":name,
            "gender":gender,
            "age":age,
            "image_url":image
        }
        return user

    results = Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(fetch_info)(i,context.new_page()) for profile in user_profiles)
    print(results)
```

below is the error I get

> greenlet.error: cannot switch to a different thread

Comment: do you try use await keyword to run your code ？  await keyword is playwright default multithreaded approach

Answer (score 1):

I have been attempting to resolve the same issue. However, from research; playwright was not designed to work in such a way on python, but it does have a synchronous structure that can be ran in a multi-threaded manner vs a parallel one. So it will allow to open and "scrape" multiple sites at once. However, it technically will not be "parallel" but can be "Multi-Threaded".  I leveraged this [code](https://gist.github.com/kumaraditya303/e6dee949dda298b35d167369955d45c6) and It allowed me to open multiple pages at once; per my needs for testing. Potentially this will work for what you are attempting to accomplish. Friendly reminder; One must create a playwright object per thread to allow it to work.  For more understanding around multi-threaded vs parallel you can refer to this site [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/multithreading-multiprocessing-python-180d0975ab29)